# How to create a new local table from a select query on remote db in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line

I can use the following command to do so as long as I create the table and the appropriate columns first. I would like the command to be able to create table for me based on the results of my query.

```
psql -h remote.host -U myuser -p 5432 -d remotedb -c "copy (SELECT view.column FROM schema.view LIMIT 10) to stdout" | psql -h localhost -U localuser -d localdb -c "copy localtable from stdin"
```

Again, it will populate the data properly if I create the table and columns ahead of time, but it would be much easier if I could automate that with a comand that creates the table according to the results of my query.

Comment: You can use a Postgres FDW and then do a `create table foo as select * from foreign_table` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: Thanks, I looked at FDW a little bit, am I correct in understanding that in order to create `foreign_table` initially, I would have to execute `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_table ( ... )` and populate it with the identical values of the remote table? If so, I think that would defeat the purpose for me, since I have a large number of tables to deal with.

Comment: No. The foreign table is like a "view" that gets the data directly from the other server. Nothing is stored locally, any select against that table will be handled by the other server.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to postgres_fdw, this works better than the solution I was aiming for anyway. This is very helpful for what I need. For anyone reading this, the only spot of trouble I ran into was giving my foreign table the same name as my remote table. This caused an error when I was querying the foreign table. Giving it a unique name resolved that. Thanks again, @a_horse_with_no_name.